# Как определить верхнюю позицию RecyclerView при скролле?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

У меня есть FAB, которая должна показываться только после начала скроллинга с конца в начало и остановки после этого действия, а скрываться - при любых других условиях. Также она должна скрываться, если RecyclerView отображает начало списка.
Вот фрагмент макета:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/refresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_up"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:onClick="onClickUpFab"
    android:src="@drawable/up_icon_white" />
```

В коде активити сейчас я использую следующий код для отслеживания скроллинга:

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                if (dy >= 0) {
                    fab_up.hide();
                } else {
                    fab_up.show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Для FAB я использую `recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);` и это работает. 
Как мне скрывать FAB в верхней позиции, если пользователь сам прокрутил список в начало, не используя кнопку?

P.S. Ранее я оборачивал RecyclerView в NestedScrollView и тогда у меня был следующий код для данной ситуации:

```
nestedScrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView nestedScrollView,
                                       int x, int y, int oldX, int oldY) {
                if (y > oldY || y == 0) {
                    fab_up.hide();
                } else if (y < oldY && y != 0) {
                    fab_up.show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Но использование NestedScrollView вызывало подлагивания и он отказался работать с моей реализацией PagingLibrary, потому я решил отказаться от его использования в данном случае.

Comment: Можно проверить: если не отображается 1 элемент в RV, то отобразить кнопку.

Comment: Можете подсказать как это проверить? Что-то с использование layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Можно проверить: если не отображается 1 элемент в RV, то отобразить кнопку. – Andrey Mihalev

Спасибо за наводку. Решил задачу, дописав условие `if (layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition() == 0) {}`. Полный код слушателя, если кому-то понадобится:

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                if (dy >= 0 || layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition() == 0) {
                    fab_up.hide();
                } else {
                    fab_up.show();
                }
            }
        });
```